# Ajax: blank space on IE

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have been working with some Ajax functions. All of them are working very well. But i have noticed that sometimes, when the function needs to write something on a `<div>` it does, but all the text appears to move one space down. This happens only on Internet Explore and only sometimes, not everytime. This does not happen on the other browsers.

I know that maybe a part of code would be appropiate, but this keeps happens on many functions, and all my codes are very long.

I only want to know if someone has experienced something like this??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your code in UTF-8? If so, you're probably facing the wrath of the BOM (Byte-Order Mark).

The BOM is not required or even desirable. Make sure it is not there when you save your UTF-8 documents. For example, in Notepad++ there is the option to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" that solves the problem nicely.

If this is not an option, try this:

```
data = data.replace(/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/,'');
```

where `data` is what you just received from AJAX and are about to insert into the document.

Comment: Do I put this on every function?

Comment: You should only have one ajax function (ie. the one that takes a URL and makes the request), so just add it to that before the `return`.